# Why does testing a non-exported static function via obj file pass when it should fail?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a DLL which sets a static boolean value in a class depending on the calling process.

Since I know that the testing environment will check for a false value, I inverted the logic in the setting code to ensure that the test failed.

When using a `public static bool` and an exported `getValue()`, this works as expected.

Switching to `private static bool`, `friend DllMain(...)` and an exported `getValue()` still works fine.

If I make the `getValue()` have internal linkage and then link the test via the .obj file produced by Visual C++, the test now passes an `EXPECT_EQ(getValue, false)` test even though the inverted logic means it should fail (i.e., getValue should return true.)

What's going on here? My guess is either covering of the value or removal of some of the code during compilation. Can I avoid this?

Loader.cpp:

```
bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    ...
    if (falseCondition) {
        myClass::isAvailable = false;
    } else {
        myClass::isAvailable = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

myClass.h

```
#ifdef MYPROJECT_EXPORTS
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class myClass {
   friend bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID);
   static bool isAvailable;

public:
   MYPROJECT_API static bool getAvailable() { return isAvailable; }
};
```

myClass.cpp

```
#include myClass.h
bool myClass::isAvailable = false;
```

In the above example code, removing the `MYPROJECT_API` macro from the `getAvailable()` line leads to the test returning `false` when it should return `true`, and fail.

Comment: The bool must be stored in the data section of *one* DLL so that all external code (EXE and any other DLLs) will use the same value.  Getting this wrong is not that easy to detect, if myClass.obj gets linked into your test program then it still seems to work correctly.  But does not in practice, other DLLs will have their own copy.

Comment: @HansPassant, That definitely sounds like what I've messed up. Unfortunately, I can't quite work out how to fix it from your explanation. Why is it that with the exported function the test executable and the built library share the bool, and without the exported function the test executable gets its own copy of the boolean? Or does the test get its own copy in both cases, but reads the DLL's boolean via the exported method, and reads its own copy via the .obj function? Perhaps I'm missing something regarding the function chosen with DLLs/.obj files?

Answer (score 0):

You can share an instance of a class / variable through all accessing applications / other DLLs.

[`#pragma data_seg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
#pragma data_seg (".mydata")
    int i = 0; 
    char a[32]n = "hello world";
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.mydata,RWS"
```

Here the string `".mydata"` is your named section. You may change this string to something else. Do not forget to change it in the `#pragma comment` for the linker too.

The sample is taken from MSDN. I have added `#pragma comment` line as I use it myself (should be explained in detail on MSDN too).

Changing one of the variables inside the `data_seg` block will also change it for any other application / DLL accessing these.